# Table.insert table argument recognized as string

Tags: string, lua, arguments, concatenation

```lua
bulletsPlayer1 = { 
   Pistol = {},
   Shotgun = {}
}

bulletsPlayer2 = { 
   Pistol = {},
   Shotgun = {}
}
```

I have these tables, and I have this function to create bullets:

```lua
function createBullet(x, y, angle, speed, weapon, player)
   local directionx = speed * math.cos(angle)
   local directiony = speed * math.sin(angle)

   table.insert(
      "bulletsPlayer"..player.."."..weapon,
      {
         positionx = x,
         positiony = y,
         directionx = directionx,
         directiony= directiony,
         speed = speed
      }
   )
end
```

For example if I call this function like this

```lua
createBullet(100,100,0,300,'Shotgun',1)
```

I am receiving this error:

> shooting.lua:77: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got string)

How can I make my code recognize the first argument of the table.insert() as my tables and not strings?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make my code recognize the first argument of the table.insert() as my tables and not strings?

That's... not how Lua works. A string is a string, a table is a table. If you want to index your players by number, store them in a table:

```lua
local bulletsPlayer = {
   {
      Pistol = {},
      Shotgun = {}
   };
   {
      Pistol = {},
      Shotgun = {}
   };
}
```

Then you can index it with a number like this

```lua
bulletsPlayer[1]["shotgun"]
```

Comment: `bulletsPlayer[1]["Shotgun"]` with capital S

Answer (score 0):

`"bulletsPlayer"..player.."." ..weapon` is a string. So the error message is exactly what you should expect.

You cannot just build variable names from strings and hope Lua will know what to do.

As `bulletsPlayer1` is a global table value you can access it through the global environment.

```
_ENV["bulletsPlayer"..player][weapon]
```

Refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2

But usually you just use table keys to get what you need. You don't build global names from strings.

Then you should have something like:

```
local players{[1] = {bullets = {shotgun = 20, pistol = 9}}}
```

But if you're going that way you might want to read something about OOP in Lua. If bullets are a property of your player, why not store that information in a player object. Also metatables can make your life much easier.